# Switching 'personalities' between app and library automatically

Tags: android, plugins, automation, build.gradle

I have two apps, A and L. They work independently, except for the fact that L has double personality: it works also as a library of A.

To do this, I made a simple bash script that edits the build.gradle of L to switch the `plugin` key between `com.android.application` and `com.android.library`. I run this bash script before building both A and L as apps.

This works fine. Yet, I would like to do this automatically when I build `A.apk` from Android Studio. Is it possible?

Comment: Would it be simpler to move the common code to a separate library module M, and have A and L be app modules that depend on M?

Comment: This is what I did, essentially. The common code is almost all of L. In any case, it would be simpler to keep doing what I do today...

Comment: "The common code is almost all of L" -- then move the rest of the code out of L and into an app module, so L can be an ordinary library module.

Comment: Ok, I did that. It was not that hard. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible , you can define your own task to call the script and link the execution with the build command .

like the following

```
task excuteScript(type: Exec) {
     workingDir "."
     commandLine 'cmd', 'script.bat'
     doLast {
         println "Executed!"
     }
 }
tasks.named("build") { finalizedBy("excuteScript") }
```

This will call the excuteScript task , each time you 'build' you project .
There might be an issue with the naming of the 'build' task , as am using spring framework this is working fine , but am not sure about Android tasks naming .

And as CommonsWare suggested , it would be way better to move the common code to a separate library module M and have your two apps use .

But i though that you might wanna know how to do it with a custom task .

Comment: Yes, I already moved the common code to a pure library, and, yes, it was good to know about the possibility. Thanks for your suggestion.